# Speed up for-loop with pointer to dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop, for-comprehension

The following for-loop works but it takes a long time. Dataframe df_customers has about 1,5 million entries and dict_customers about 500 000 rows.

```
for i in range(len(df_customers)):
    df_customers.iloc[i, j] = dict_customers[df_customers.iloc[i,k]]
```

My question is: How to speed up the for-loop?

Dataframe df_customers contains customer features, a.o. CustomerID. One customer has several rows (so not unique per row).

A dictionary dict_customers contains the unique customer IDs (keys) and the number of visits per customer (values).

I would like to add a new column k to the Dataframe df_customers that has the number of visits which are retrieved from the dictionary.

I solved this problem with a for-loop with df_customers:
i is rows
j is the new column with the visits
k is the existing column with the CustomerIDs

Note: the CustomerID starts at 100 000.

I tried the following comprehension:

```
df_customers.j-column = [dict_customers[df_custumers.k-column[i]] for i in range(len(df_customers))]
```

The written comprehension code does not work. It keeps all the values 0 (as initialized).
The expected output is that per CustomerID the customer visits from the dictionary are stored in the new df_customers column k.

Comment: where did you get `k` in the 1st code fragment?

Comment: `j = df_customers.columns.get_loc('j-column')`

Comment: `k = df_customers.columns.get_loc('k-column')`

Answer (score 0):

> I found a solution:

1. Create a list of the dictionary values (the CustomerIDs are
   sequential):

   `list_values = [v for v in dict_customers.values()]`
2. Create an array of this list (also to speed up): 
   `array_values = np.array(list_values`
3. The comprehension returns the values of the array pointed by the
   df_customers j column (and corrected because CustomerID starts from
   100 000 and the index of the array at 0): 

   `df_customers['j-column'] = array_values[df_customers.iloc[i,k] - 100000] for i in range(len(df_customers))]`